# How sed can merge some words?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file that filled with `'/*'` characters, and each row like:

A/n B/v **C/n D/n** E/w **F/v G/v H/v** ...

A,B...H are words. I want to merge continues same '/*' characters, say:

A/n B/v **CD/n** E/w **FGH/v** ...

I'm new to `sed` or `awk` order, and what should I do? Thx.

Comment: Have you attempted any solution? Please, post your code, what have you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
sed -e ":a" -e "s#\(/.\) *\([^/]*\)\1#\2\1#g;ta"
```

explaination:

define a label

```
:a
```

change this pattern

- a group (1) composed of / than a char
- some space
- a group (2) of char that are non /
- same group of group 1

to

- group 2 followed by group 1

  s#(/.) *([^/]*)\1#\2\1#g

If change occur, go to label a

```
t a
```

Comment: Great! Here's a generalized solution that will work for markers longer than one character `sed -e ":a" -e "s#\(/[^\s]\+\)\s\+\([^\s/]\+\)\1#\2\1#g;ta"`

Comment: You can reduce the whole line to : `sed ':a;s#\(/.\) *\([^/]*\)\1#\2\1#g;ta'`. Very nice solution.

Comment: reduction is not possible with posix version, that why i put this.  you are right in gnu sed. good point

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, here's a quick AWK solution:

```
awk '{ out=""; cw=""; ct=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,a,"/"); if(a[2]==ct) cw = cw a[1]; else { if (cw||ct) out = (out ? out OFS : "") cw "/" ct; cw=a[1]; ct = a[2]; }; }; if(cw) out = (out ? out OFS : "") cw "/" ct; print out; }'
```

Obviously, it's not so elegant as @NeronLeVelu's sed magic, but might work faster for big inputs.

Example input:

```
A/noun B/verb C/noun D/noun E/adj F/verb G/verb H/verb
```

Example output:

```
A/noun B/verb CD/noun E/adj FGH/verb
```